# How to use require and module.exports in Node without repetition?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a class file in Node called `chart.js` that relies  `moment.js` and a bunch of other external dependencies:

```
var moment = require('moment');
...
var Chart = {
  doSomething: function() { 
  } ...
};
module.exports = Chart;
```

Now I want to use this `chart.js` module in my `index.js` file, so I am importing it as follows:

```
var chart = require('chart');
chart.doSomething();
```

But this gives me import errors:

```
ReferenceError: moment is not defined
```

Do I need to re-include all the `require('moment')` statements at the top of `index.js` too?

Surely I should be able to change the requirements for the chart file without having to amend the index file too?

Comment: It is unclear where you are trying to use the library - is it within the `doSomething()` function? Is it somewhere in the *index.js* file?

Comment: index.js should not be throwing this error. are you sure chart.js works on it's own?

Comment: Are you can show you doSomething method?

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need to specify `require('moment')` in every file. Make sure moment JS library is installed correctly and that it is in your `node_modules` directory.

For Node modules installed with npm, you can require them with `require('moduleName')`, so `require('moment')` is fine. But for your own modules, you have to specify the relative path and the file name. So, assuming `index.js` and `chart.js` are in the same level, in your `index.js` you would do `require('./chart.js')`.

Other notes: don't capitalize variable names unless you are using a class constructor function. In your code you are using simple object literal, not a constructor, so there's no need to capitalize the variable name, `Chart`.